# Identity server 4 in ASP.NET Core 3.1 with MongoDb

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb, asp.net-core, identityserver3

I am trying to implement Identity Server 4 with ASP.NET Core 3.1 and MongoDb. I found the example over here: https://github.com/souzartn/IdentityServer4.Samples.Mongo

I am not sure is it good to use mongodb for identity server or SQL Server is better.

Is there any step by step process to understand how identity server implemented with mongo DB.

I want to store the data with user details in the mongo collection with roles and activities

I am new to the mongo DB so please let me know how can I create a Identity Server.

I found the example above but not understood properly.

Can please any one let me know the step by step process

Comment: The best recommendation I can give you is [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jARHHUsljeo&t=427s) playlist on youtube. Start from episode 9 and then onward. This has nothing to do with MongoDB, but once you understand the in's and out's of the Identity server, going to https://github.com/souzartn/IdentityServer4.Samples.Mongo will be easy.

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate IdentityServer with MongoDB quite easily. The user's account and role management stuffs will be stored in MongoDB and these are interacted with ASP.NET Core Identity. IdentityServer will provide authentication as usual with access tokens, id tokens etc. The whole integration is provided in [this article](https://www.yogihosting.com/identityserver-aspnet-core-identity-mongodb-database/).